# How to deal single element json array when converting sql xml to json convertion in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml

I am working on convert SQL output XML to JSON conversion in C#. when I convert XML  that have multiple set element to JSON the output like JSON array at the sametime XML have single single set then output like JSON object. How to I maintain output as JSON array in both case?

Case 1:

```
<root>
   <DATA>
    <NAME>NAYAN</NAME>
    <LOCATION>CHENNAI</LOCATION>
  </DATA>
   <DATA>
    <NAME>TARA</NAME>
    <LOCATION>CHENNAI</LOCATION>
  </DATA>
 </root>
```

Result:

```
{
   "DATA": [
      {
         "NAME": "NAYAN",
         "LOCATION": "CHENNAI"
      },
      {
         "NAME": "TARA",
         "LOCATION": "CHENNAI"
      }
   ]
}
```

Case 2:

```
<root>
   <DATA>
    <NAME>NAYAN</NAME>
    <LOCATION>CHENNAI</LOCATION>
  </DATA>
 </root>
```

Result:

```
{
   "DATA": {
      "NAME": "NAYAN",
      "LOCATION": "CHENNAI"
   }
}
```

Expectation:

```
{
   "DATA":[
 {
      "NAME": "NAYAN",
      "LOCATION": "CHENNAI"
   }
]
}
```

This my C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = @"<root>
      <DATA>
        <NAME>NAYAN</NAME>
        <LOCATION>CHENNAI</LOCATION>
      </DATA>
    </root>";

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,true);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Comment: Please could you show the code you're using?

Comment: @JonSkeet sure. now  I have added the code in my question.

Comment: Okay. Is the structure always the same? If so, I'd personally just iterate over the XML directly (I'd use LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument` though) and create a `JArray`. It would be very simple code - but it wouldn't work if you need it to handle varying structures.

Comment: @ArulmuruganK, i added my answer below if it help you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i created a simple utility function that can take your `DATA` token and parse it to Array if `DATA` contains either object or array.

```
public class Utility
{
    public static string JsonParser(string json)
    {
        JToken jTokenMain = JToken.Parse(json);

        JToken jToken = jTokenMain["DATA"];

        List<object> list = new List<object>();

        if (jToken is JArray)
        {
            list = jToken.ToObject<List<object>>();
        }
        else if (jToken is JObject)
        {
            list.Add(jToken.ToObject<object>());
        }

        JToken data = JToken.FromObject(list);

        jTokenMain["DATA"] = data;

        return jTokenMain.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can use above function like

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);

string formattedJson = Utility.JsonParser(json);
```

---

**Edit:**

In your xml `<root>` is the 0th level element and `<DATA>` is the 1st level element and its name can be anything and you want this element to be Array in json whether its object or array in xml.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
//XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml");

Dictionary<string, object> dict = doc.Root.Elements()
   .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => new
   {
       Name = y.Element("NAME").Value,
       Location = y.Element("LOCATION").Value
   })
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => (object)y.ToList());

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Case 1:**  (1st level element name is `DATA`)

```
<root>
<DATA>
  <NAME>NAYAN</NAME>
  <LOCATION>CHENNAI</LOCATION>
</DATA>
</root>
```

**Output:**  (Json with key name is `DATA`)

[image]

**Case 2:**  (1st level element name is `SAMPLE`)

```
<root>
<SAMPLE>
  <NAME>NAYAN</NAME>
  <LOCATION>CHENNAI</LOCATION>
</SAMPLE>
</root>
```

**Output:**  (Json with key name is `SAMPLE`)

[image]

Comment: I already try like this. but input XML is generated from SQL FOR XML PATH. so element names are dynamic. is this any possible to correct it from sql?

Comment: you mean `DATA, NAME, LOCATION` are dynamic?

Comment: I talk about element name like 'DATA'. I created a stored procedure that result element is  'DATA'. in future customer want add new element than I need to change   stored procedure. It is easy for me but i need to change c# code also. so my idea is need to inticate 'this is element is json' in my stored procedure. There is any possible when FOR XML PATH features?

Comment: means, in your xml root is 0th level element and DATA is 1st level element and its name can be anything and you want this elememt to be Array in json whether its object or array in xml, right?

Comment: Its too late to update answer. I can update it tomorrow. Stay in touch :)

Comment: i updated my answer with dynamic name of 1st level element in xml. kindly view **Edit** section in answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much bro. I found some alternate solution on newtonsoft. in this solution we are indicate a json array at sql xML. please find the below link.               https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm

Comment: its nice that you found proper solution for your problem. but if you found my answer useful then you can mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for you help, Bro.